# RequireJS: Reading configuration from app.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In app.js, I am writing configurations for my project.I want to pick the version number of jquery from some external file config.js instead of hard coding it in app.js. How can I achieve this?

I have pasted code for app.js, config.js and index.html below:

**config.js**

```
define(function() {
  var Config = {
    jquery: "3.1.0"
  };
  return Config;
});
```

**Index.html:**

```
<script src="require.js" data-main="js/app"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
     jquery: serverUrl + "/jquery-3.1.0.min",
  }
});
```

I cannot move requirejs.config() to config.js file as serverUrl is the variable used which I can't retrieve from config.js according to my project structure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you want would just be to load a configuration file before your `app.js` and refer to it.

```
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script src="require.js" data-main="js/app"></script>
```

`config.js` could contain:

```
window.fooConfig = {
  serverUrl: 'some appropriate URL',
}
```

I use `window` explicitly to make it clear I'm putting something in the global space *on purpose*. `fooConfig` for the name is just an example of what could be used for an application named `foo`. You can select something as unique as you need to avoid a clash with other code.

Then your `app.js` would do:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
     jquery: fooConfig.serverUrl + "/jquery-3.1.0.min",
  }
});
```

Comment: I have no way to get serverUrl in config.js. It can be accessed only from app.js. This is a limitation from my project. Config.js is supposed to hold only jquery version which has to be used in app.js.